# How to fetch warnings from the dotnet build command

Tags: c#, .net, shell, exit-code

Given a .Net C# project I want to check if the build contains warnings. When running the command

```
dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build"
```

I get the expected output

```
Build succeeded.
    2 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

But the exit code is 0, so how do I know if that build contains warnings?

I created a shell script to play around

```
#!/bin/bash

dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo ">>> Success"
else
  echo ">>> Contains warnings or errors"
fi

read
```

but how can I extend the script to check for a successful build with warnings? The configured CI pipelines should pass but I want to mark them as unstable if warnings occured.

I would like to avoid Regex magic if possible.

---

Edit:

I don't want to add the flag `-warnaserror` because then CI pipelines will fail and you won't get to know if build errors occured or the code style is just bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is simply add /WarnAsError to your dotnet build.

Example code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
           int x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of dotnet build:

```
dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.0+4242f381a for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
Program.cs(10,17): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used [ConsoleApp1.csproj]
  ConsoleApp1 -> ConsoleApp1.dll

Build succeeded.

\Program.cs(10,17): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used [ConsoleApp1.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.79
```

Output of dotnet build /WarnAsError:

```
dotnet build /WarnAsError
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.0+4242f381a for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored ConsoleApp1.csproj (in 60 ms).
Program.cs(10,17): error CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used [ConsoleApp1.csproj]
  ConsoleApp1 -> ConsoleApp1.dll

Build FAILED.

Program.cs(10,17): error CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used [ConsoleApp1.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.00
```

EDIT:
OP requested to not fail the build upon warning.

Something you can try, is to have the warnings be written to a file and afterwards count the number of lines in that file.

Exmample:

I took the code above and added several variables:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;
```

Now when I compile, I get 5 warnings. Now I added this to my dotnet build:

```
$warningsFile = "SomeFile.log"
dotnet build -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$warningsFile;warningsonly"
```

Afterwards I can simply count the number of lines in that file.
Using powershell:

```
gc $warningsFile | Measure-Object -Line
```

Results in:

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
    5
```

I'm not sure whether this will work in all cases, but at least it will tell you whether you had warnings or not.
Hope this helps you

Comment: hey, thanks for your help. unfortunately I don't want to use the flag because then the stage is treated as failed

Comment: Hmmm yeah, I think the best way to capture them is to write the entire output to a variable, echo them and performing a regex on the variable.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that the regex might fetch other words as well :S So I'm not sure about this solution https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7749#issuecomment-498151801

Comment: Updated my answer, it now includes a way to find the number of warning lines @OlafSvenson

Comment: this might work, I would like to try it out.  Would you mind explaining these two?

`/fl1` and `/flp1`

Comment: You can find relevant information about those flags here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019#save-the-log-output-to-multiple-files

Comment: yeah, thanks. The build command works fine. But when running it from a shell script https://pastebin.com/jGnm7rpz and calling it via `./build.sh` I get the outout `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
 Switch: C:/Program Files/Git/fl1`

Comment: Try placing at the end of your dotnet build call, after the "-consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build""

Comment: Ah, that might be the case for a bash script, had not tried that. What you can do is replace the "/fl1" with "-fl1". I will edit my answer

Comment: awesome! This works `dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly"` but the last thing is: why does it generate a `msbuild1.log` file? I would expect the name to be the value of the variable

Comment: yes, you are correct, one would assume so. Apparently, this is not the entire command we need. 
What you need to do is add logFile before, so entire call would be: `dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly"`

Comment: yes, that worked. thank you very much! this is the current file https://pastebin.com/fEbp4f8m :)